# Novice question: how do you approach solving an equation like this?

Tags: functional-equations

How do you find $f(x)$ if you know that: $$f(2x) = 2f(x) - f(x)^2$$

The result is: $f(x)=1-e^{cx}$ (where $c$ is an arbitrary constant).

What would be the steps to get to the result?

Comment: You want to assume $f$ is continuous, otherwise there are more exotic solutions.

Comment: @ChristianF: The case $f(x)=0$ is already covered by the given function, by selecting $c=0$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

With $g(x)=1-f (x) $ you obtain:
$$g (2x) =g (x)^2$$
You can then look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1457606/550182)