# Find all continuous functions $f$ defined over $\mathbb{R}^{+*}$ such that $f(x) =\sqrt{2+ f(x^2)}.$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Find all continuous functions $f$ defined over $\mathbb{R}^{+*}$ such that $f(x) =\sqrt{2+ f(x^2)}.$

I found the constant function $f(x)=2$ and the function $f(x)=x+1/x$, but are there other functions?
i start from the obious fact that $f(x) > 0$ as by definition of $f$...we deduce that $f(x) \geq \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{...+\sqrt{2+f(x^{2^n})}}{}}}} \geq \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{...+\sqrt{2+...}}{}}}} =2$
...
so $f(x) \geq 2$ for every positive real number...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What is $\Bbb R^*$?

Comment: @MartinR Unless the OP says otherwise I assume it's $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, so denoted to emphasize it's a group under $\times$.

Comment: Martin R :  $R^{+*}$ is the set of positive real numbers and $R^{*}$ is the set of real numbers different from zero

Comment: The function $f : x \to x + \frac{1}{x}$ does not work (take $x  = 2$).

Notice that one must have $f(1) = \sqrt{2 + f(1)}$ hence $f(1)$ must be the positive root of $X^2 - X -2$ whence $f(1) = 2$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2819684/can-non-linear-continuous-and-odd-function-fx-satisfy-f2x-2fx
j isn't automatically be linear when f(x) is continuous

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)^2-f(x^2)=2$$
let $x=e^t$ and $g=f\circ \exp$
$$ g(t)^2 - g(2t) = 2 $$
let $g=2\cdot h$
$$ h(2t) = 2\cdot h(t)^2 - 1 $$
let $h=\cosh\circ j$
$$ \cosh( j(2t)) = \cosh(2\cdot j(t)) $$
and you get solutions of the form
$$ j(t)=\alpha t,\qquad h(t)=\cosh(\alpha t),\qquad g(t)=2\cosh(\alpha t),\qquad f(x)=2\cosh(\alpha \log x)=x^\alpha+x^{-\alpha}.$$
Then it is not difficult to show that the constant solution and the solutions $x^{\alpha}+x^{-\alpha}$ are the only continuous solutions.