# Solving a quadratic functional equation in $f(2x)$

Tags: functions, derivatives, functional-equations

Find all differentiable functions with $f'(0)=1$, such that they satisfy the following functional equation:

$$ f(2x) = 2f^2(x) -4f(x) + 3$$

[image]

So, here's what I tried:

[image]

And now, I'm stuck because I have no clue how to simplify the final limit.
Plus, I think there must be a more general method to solve functional equations of the kind $f(nx) = g(f(x))$ where $g(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, or at least the case $f(2x) = quadratic in f(x)$.

So, what can I do ahead of this?

Comment: $f^2(0)$ normally means $f(f(0))$ not $f(0)^2$. Better to write $f(x)^2$ in he equation if that is what you mean.

Comment: ah, sorry, i'll correct that

Comment: never mind, there's an error with uploading a second image, please understand it as ive shown it, sorry

Comment: "$f(x)$ is (only) derivable at $0$" (as in 4.3) or "it is differentiable over $\mathbb{R}$ with $f'(0) = 1$" (as in the first sentence of the question)?

Comment: This is a nice problem. Can you cite the name of the book or resource where you found this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Sharpening Mathematical Skills; it's beautiful collection of problems in real analysis

Comment: You will find this problem in a section called aperitif

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First note that differentiating the relation
$$
f(2x) = 2f(x)^2 - 4f(x)+3
$$
at $x=0$ we obtain
$$
2f'(0) = 4f'(0)f(0) - 4f'(0)
$$
and since $f'(0)=1$ this gives $f(0)=3/2$.

Instead of your choice of $g$, take
$$
g(x) = 2(f(x)-1),
$$
and thus $g(0)=1$. Then you obtain the functional equation
$$
g(2x) = g(x)^2,
$$
where $g'(0)=2$. Now, we have that
$$
g(x) = g\left( \frac{x}{2} \right)^2 \geq 0
$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. If $g(x_0)=0$ for some $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$, then by induction we can prove that $g(2^{-n}x_0)=0$ for all positive integer $n$, so taking the limit as $n\to \infty$ we obtain that $g(0)=0$ (note that $g$ is continuous at $0$ since it is differentiable at $0$), but this contradicts $g(0)=1$. Thus we have that $g(x)>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now, define
$$
h(x) = \log(g(x)).
$$
Here $\log$ is the natural logarithm. Then you obtain the functional equation
$$
h(2x) = 2h(x)
$$
with $h(0)=0$ and $h$ differentiable at $0$. This equation is well known and is solved for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1457606). Note that by the first answer to that question, you only need the differentiability at $0$, not on $\mathbb{R}$.

Thus by the answer to the above mentioned question, we have that $h(x)=ax$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus $g(x)=e^{ax}$ and hence
$$
f(x) = 1 + \frac{e^{ax}}{2}.
$$
From the condition $f'(0)=1$ you can show that $a=2$ so
$$
f(x) = 1 + \frac{e^{2x}}{2}
$$
is the only solution to the given functional equation.

Comment: Oh, okay that's a smarter choice of g, really nice clear answer, thank you!